# How to add Metatags/Search data to a domain

Tags: dns, metadata

I have two websites, one is the main website with everything on it, and the other which is a domain with a simple redirect to the main site. I just want to know how to add metadata/keywords/description and such to this domain without creating a new site.
How can I do this?